# CakePHP: Cake Bake HasOne association

Tags: cakephp

I use the following db setup:

users:

- id
- name
- country_id (FK)

countries

- id
- name

I use this setup for data integrity. When a user adds an account, a country dropdown is presented in the add form through a find(list).

The problem is that while Cake Baking, I can not choose a HasOne relationship between users and countries. I can only choose that a User BelongsTo a country.

What goes wrong here? Do I need to add the HasOne association manually or is the BelongsTo relationship correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean hasMany, as in a country has many users. Yes, you'll have to define that in Country model, if you wish to have that relationship.

Comment: Thanks, but what do I define in the Users table then? Or is it enough in this relationship to have it only defined in the Country table?

Comment: if you want a country has many users, you have to define hasMany in Country model. If you want a user belongsTo a country, you have to define belongsTo in User model.